# Found Duplicate PV in LVM disk scan

Tags: linux, centos, mount, lvm

I have a VPS, and I attached another hard disk to it. It contains the same partitions I have on my current disk; it has `/` and `/boot` and `swap`. I need all data on the `/` partition. Here is the output of `lsblk`:

```
NAME                               MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                                  8:0    0   30G  0 disk 
├─sda1                               8:1    0  500M  0 part /boot
├─sda2                               8:2    0    4G  0 part [SWAP]
└─sda3                               8:3    0 25.5G  0 part 
   └─VolGroup-LogVol00 (dm-0)       253:0    0 25.5G  0 lvm  /
sdb                                  8:16   0   30G  0 disk 
├─sdb1                               8:17   0  500M  0 part 
├─sdb2                               8:18   0    4G  0 part 
└─sdb3                               8:19   0 25.5G  0 part 
sr0                                 11:0    1 1024M  0 rom  
loop0                                7:0    0  100G  0 loop 
└─docker-253:0-1568490-pool (dm-1) 253:1    0  100G  0 dm   
loop1                                7:1    0    2G  0 loop     
└─docker-253:0-1568490-pool (dm-1) 253:1    0  100G  0 dm
```

I want all data on `sdb3`, but the problem is I can't mount it:

```
mount /dev/sdb3 /mnt
```

The output is:

```
mount: unknown filesystem type 'LVM2_member'
```

I found some solutions, but they didn't work in my case, because of `duplicate PV` found by `pvs`:

```
  Found duplicate PV 4nqduWJXs1chO3eC9Wfbsg36keLDd0Mc: using /dev/sdb3 not /dev/sda3
    PV         VG       Fmt  Attr PSize  PFree
    /dev/sdb3  VolGroup lvm2 a--  25.51g    0
```

also the output of `vgdisplay` is:

```
  Found duplicate PV 4nqduWJXs1chO3eC9Wfbsg36keLDd0Mc: using /dev/sdb3 not /dev/sda3
    --- Volume group ---
    VG Name               VolGroup
    System ID             
    Format                lvm2
    Metadata Areas        1
    Metadata Sequence No  2
    VG Access             read/write
    VG Status             resizable
    MAX LV                0
    Cur LV                1
    Open LV               1
    Max PV                0
    Cur PV                1
    Act PV                1
    VG Size               25.51 GiB
    PE Size               4.00 MiB
    Total PE              6530
    Alloc PE / Size       6530 / 25.51 GiB
    Free  PE / Size       0 / 0   
    VG UUID               tR42OL-gnEO-IyTY-1Zxf-u7Qc-R2Kc-K73ddf
```

I found some solutions on a ReHat customers portal, but it wasn't the solution. It was somehow irrelevant, I need to use `/dev/sda3` instead of `/dev/sdb3`. And also, I need access to all data in `/dev/sdb3`, because the data is critical to me.

Comment: Is this extra disk image just a byte-by-byte copy of your disk attached to `/dev/sda` that has been created while ago? What `vgdisplay` shows?

Comment: it's not a byte-by-byte copy, it was my server hard disk on vps, i installed new server with same partition table and attach the hard from previous VPS,

Comment: I'm not up-to-date on multipathing, but it's possible what you have here is the same physical disk presented as two different LUNs, which then get (mis)translated into two different block devices (sda vs sdb).  So what @Serge suggested: you might be looking at bit-for-bit copy, but because it's actually the same physical device. Be careful here! 

Anyway, if it's the same physical device, you'll find all your stuff already in `/`, on sda3.

Comment: Then it is very strange that you have duplicate UUIDs. The hosting company does its job in a lazy way: it seems they just copy the pre-created image and do not care on possible conflicts. See the answer I will post shortly

Comment: I know this is old but I just want to add the following to your last sentence about data being critical: please do for your sake backup nightly (or if necessary daily) then before anything risky. Just a reminder really since so many people ignore it due to it being inconvenient or forgetting (which is why setting up nightly/daily backup is the way to go).

Answer (score 3):

The best way to recover in your situation is to detach the disk you have now attached to `sda` and attach this disk in question to `sda`, then boot from it.

After you get to console, change all PV's UUIDs:

> pvchange -a -u

change VG's UUID:

> vgchange -u VloGroupName

and rename your volume group to a new name

> vgrename OldVolumeGroup{Path|Name|UUID} NewVolumeGroupName

Then reattach this drive to `sdb`, and the original drive to `sda`. After a reboot you should see two volume groups with their own PV's and LV's

Edit:

Alternatively (and shorter) do all above with the drive attached to `sda` while `sdb` is disconnected, then attach `sdb`

Comment: i detach /dev/sdb and the run pvchange -au, but it doesn't change /dev/sda3,it says Volume group containing /dev/sda3 has active logical volumes and Physical volume /dev/sda3 not changed

Comment: Then I have no recipe as it seems you can't do with this VM whatever you like - you only can mount the volumes you have. As an alternative, boot a VM from that old image, copy the files you need to some other location (ftp, your local site, e.t.c.)